# Unable to install php7.1-bcmath ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, php-7.1, bcmath

I have a VPS with ubuntu 14.04, php7.1-fpm installed and running for ages.
I am trying to install php7.1-bcmath. it keeps saying

> E: Unable to locate package php7.1-bcmath
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-bcmath'

I have already tried adding

> add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

and it says:

> Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
> gpg: keyring /tmp/tmph26v3afu/secring.gpg' created
>
> gpg: keyring /tmp/tmph26v3afu/pubring.gpg' created
>
> gpg: requesting key E5267A6C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
>
> gpg:/tmp/tmph26v3afu/trustdb.
>
> gpg: trustdb created
>
> gpg: key E5267A6C:public key "Launchpad PPA for Ondřej Surý" imported
> gpg: Total number processed: 1
>
> gpg: imported: 1 (RSA: 1)
> OK

I have also done:

> sudo apt-get update

but even after this it says

> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-bcmath'

Any help is appericiated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the ppa:ondrej/php is no longer supported for trusty(ubuntu 14.04) so i went ahead and ran:

```
do_release_upgrade()
```

and i was upgraded to xenial (ubuntu 16.04)
Thats the only way i could get a php extension that i did not already have